# How Do I Migrate Data From A WordPress Multisite Environment to a Singlesite Environment?

Tags: mysql, wordpress

I have a wordpress site running as a part of the multisite website. I want to migrate the multisite wordpress site data from a multisite setup to a new singlesite setup. Please let me know what is the best method for such a migration.

Comment: https://wordpress.org/support/topic/move-from-multi-site-to-single-site/

Comment: Thanks for the link. It's useful!